# Sending a response without calling render() from a Mojolicious::Lite application

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I am writing a "partial proxy" in `Mojolicious::Lite`.  Certain requests (depending on the query path, and on the values of the parameters) generate a request to another server, while others are handled locally.

There is a [nice proxy example](https://gist.github.com/42c32258713b34f3604e), but it totally overrides the request/response handling and thus is not suitable to my needs.

Currently, I am marshalling the response via

```
$self->render(data => $res->body, code => $res->code);
```

Unfortunately, this does not take into account different content types.  Using `Mojolicious::Type` does not help,
because I need a reverse mapping from the content type
in `$res` to the `format` in `render()`;  besides,
the number of possible render formats is significantly smaller
than the number of possible content types.

So ideally, instead of the `$self->render()` call above
I need a way to say "here, I got a response in `$res`;
please return it back to the client as is".

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, the trick was to replace `render()` call with

```
$self->tx->res($res);
$self->rendered($res->code);
```